# Pulling an Image from Private Registry in Kubernetes cronjob fails

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, kubectl

I am pulling an image from a private repository on gitlab and running a cronjob in kubernetes. Since it is a private repo I would also have to supply the imagePullSecrets. but I noticed it gives an error because a cronjob doesn't accept the imagePullSecrets tag. It gives the following error. Does that mean I can't use an image from a private repository in a cronjob?

```
error: error validating "cron.yml": error validating data: ValidationError(CronJob.spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.containers[0]): unknown field "imagePullSecrets" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Comment: Hi, I think it works `kubectl explain CronJob.spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec --recursive `, As I understand you are using this field inside container field.

Answer (score 11):

The `imagePullSecrets` field is not a per container field - you need to set that at `CronJob.spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.imagePullSecrets` instead of `CronJob.spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.containers.imagePullSecrets`. You can see an example for a Pod [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry#create-a-pod-that-uses-your-secret).

Comment: `kubectl explain CronJob.spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.imagePullSecrets` would be the right place

Comment: No worries. Cheers

Comment: Is it too much to ask to put an example here?